# I'm having trouble with cpp code to insert elements in a binary tree

Tags: c++, codeblocks, binary-search-tree

I've tried this way to insert elements in a binary tree in code blocks. The program got compiled but got a run time error and the program stopped running.  Could some one please help me out in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>     

#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class bst;
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *lc;
    node *rc;
};
class bst
{
public:
node *root;
bst()
{
    root = NULL;
}
void search(int, node **, node **);
void insert(int);
void display(node *, int);
};
void bst::search(int item, node **par, node **loc)
{
node *current;
node *ptr;
if(root == NULL)
{
    *par = NULL;
    *loc = NULL;
    return;
}
if(item == root->data)
{
    *par = NULL;
    *loc = root;
    return;
}
if(item < root->data)
    current = root->lc;
else
    current = root->rc;
ptr = root;
while(current != NULL)
{
    if(item == current->data)
    {
        *par = ptr;
        *loc = current;
        return;
    }
    ptr = current;
    if(item < current->data)
        current = current->lc;
    else
        current = current->rc;
}
*par = current;
*loc = NULL;

}
void bst::insert(int item)
{
node *parent;
node *location;
node *temp;
search(item, &parent, &location);
temp = new node;
temp->data = item;
temp->lc = NULL;
temp->rc = NULL;
if(item < parent->data)
    parent->lc = temp;
else
    parent->rc = temp;
}
void bst::display(node *ptr, int level)
{
if(ptr != NULL)
{
    display(ptr->rc, level+1);
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<level;i++)
        cout<<"  ";
    cout<<ptr->data;
    display(ptr->lc, level+1);
}
}

int main()
{
int ch, num;
bst b;
while(1)
{
    cout<<"1. INSERT ; 2. DISPLAY ; 3. EXIT "<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your choice"<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: cout<<"Enter the number to insert"<<endl;
                cin>>num;
                b.insert(num);
                break;
        case 2: b.display(b.root, 1);
                break;
        case 3: exit(0);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be way easier for us if you provide the text of the errors.

Comment: Indeed. Note though that generally, on SO we don't fix compile errors; we ask for you to get the code compiling first, so that questions cover the functioning of valid code rather than correcting typos.

Comment: See the guide on SSCCE.org

Answer (score 0):

In this line `search(item, &parent, &location);` you are calling the function `search` with arguments of types `int`, `node**` and `node**`. It in fact expects `int`, `node*` and `node*`. You should change the function declaration to `search(int, node**, node**)`.

Comment: I think the double pointer is the one the OP was going for. The `search` function acts as if it is.

Comment: @chris yes it seems you are right. I will change my answer accordingly .Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @IvayloStrandjev ! I got it compiled.

Comment: @zoska When I try to insert an element I'm getting a popup saying "A problem cause the program to stop working correctly".

Comment: @user2820154 please post another question with this problem as it is not related to the original post. You should always provide as much information as possible on the problems that you face. We can not help you otherwise